# Internet Explorer control uses IE7's own settings for ClearType and font size, can I override them?

Tags: internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7, controls, cleartype, embedded-control

I'm embedding an IE control into my C++ application. The problem is that although system-wide, ClearType is disabled, IE7 has its own separate setting, and unless I specifically disable that too, text inside the IE control will be antialiased while the rest of the app will not.

The same goes for IE7's font size setting.

It wouldn't be a problem for me to set up IE7 accordingly, but it would affect the experience of users of my app. Can the IE control's cleartype usage and font size be programmatically controlled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, you can implement IDocHostUIHandler on your OLE client site and return a registry path from IDocHostUIHandler::GetOptionKeyPath. The settings from this registry path will be used instead of the user's settings.

References:

- [IDocHostUIHandler::GetOptionKeyPath Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753258(VS.85).aspx)
- [IDocHostUIHandler Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753260(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The IE control uses the user settings, so the short answer is no.